# double quotes not properly closed

Tags: java

```
String query="insert into employee values('"+e.getId()+",'"+e.getName()+"',"+e.getSalary()+")";
```

Whats wrong with this code.Error -String literals are not properly closed by double - quotes;

Comment: Print your query and you should get `insert into employee values('someid,'somename',somesalary)` - then have a look at `'someid`.

Comment: @thomas good spot! It's not closing the id properly, should look like `'"...+e.getId()+"','"...` notice the `'` at end before `,`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of quotes:

```
String query="insert into employee values('"+e.getId()+"','"+e.getName()+"','"+e.getSalary()+"')";
```

Namely the closing one on `e.getId()` and both on `e.getSalary()`

Comment: salary might be numeric

Comment: @Lothar true, but generally I'd imagine id to have a better chance so I assumed the OP missed this too.

Answer (score 1):

You have only a single quote for `ID`. Remove it (id sounds numeric) or add a closing one accordingly.

Even better, use `PreparedStatement` and set the parameters using the corresponding methods to avoid the whole quoting-topic and prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

A quote is missing for the id field

```
String query="insert into employee values('"+e.getId()+"','"+e.getName()+"',"+e.getSalary()+")";
```